# CouchBase reset password with exclamation (!)

Tags: docker, couchbase

I want to upload dump to Couchbase bucket. I use `cbrestore` tool, however it asks for a password. I have a password which contains `!`. When I try to add a password parameter to the command line it says:

```
!pass: event not found
```

I found information that there should be a a `cbreset_password tool`, however it is a docker images and somehow it does not contain the tool. In all other cases I need to type old password which I can not type because of exclamation mark.

How else is possible to reset the password?
Is it possible to download the tool manually, upload to the docker container and reset the password?
Or maybe it is possible to do using UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In all other cases I need to type old password which I can not type because of exclamation mark

Check first if that same password would work if you [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) the exclamation mark:

```
%21pass
```

If that does not work, you need to make sure the shell does not interpret '!'.
Try escaping the character: `\!pass` on Linux, `^!pass` on Windows.

Or, as pointed out by [avsej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98509/avsej) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867790/couchbase-reset-password-with-exclamation/44867845?noredirect=1#comment76716223_44867845):

> you can patch your CLI scripts to escape the passwords:
>   See [this thread](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/cbbackupwrapper-not-working-with-passwords-that-contain-parentheses/12822/2).
>
> > It seems like a bug in the python script, it should really quote the password (and maybe other arguments) when building command line
> >
> > /opt/couchbase/lib/python/cbbackupwrapper

Comment: It says: ERROR: unable to access the REST API - please check your username (-u) and password (-p)
And I know that password is correct because I can log in to the UI console

Comment: Also you can patch your CLI scripts to escape the passwords: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/cbbackupwrapper-not-working-with-passwords-that-contain-parentheses/12822/2

Comment: @avsej Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC, thank you very much! simple escaping with \!pass helped me. appreciate your help. My head was about to blow up with this simple issue :)